# I want to know how can I use <sub></sub> in a matrix in markdown

Tags: latex, markdown

I want to write a matrix and which element in the matrix has a 
Subscript, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuAHF.png).

I tried to write the markdown code

```
$$x=\left[\begin{matrix}(x(<sub>2</sub>))\\3\\2\\40\end{matrix}\right]$$
```

but it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy8AN.png).

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like markdown to me, but rather like LaTeX. Try this one

```
$$x=\left[\begin{matrix}x_0\\x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{matrix}\right]$$
```

To make a subscript in LaTeX, use the underscore. If its more than one character, use curly braces `x_{10}`.